# RadioButtonFor set bool based on 'Checked'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, radio-button

I have a table with rows, and one column per row has a radio button for a boolean property `IsPrimary`.  Now only one row should be allowed the `IsPrimary` property.

My razor code:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsPrimary, "True", new { @Name="nameIsPrimary", @id=""})
```

which works great for validating that only one button is selected.  My issue is, I simply want the `IsPrimary` property set to true for that object, and false for all the others.  I thought this would be easy (and it probably is) but I can't seem to figure it out.  As it stands, it always return false for all items.

I believe I need to relate it to the 'checked' value for the button, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.  Thankyou for any help.

Comment: Are you using `FormCollection` in your action, or a strongly-typed model?

Comment: I have a strongly typed model

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a custom model binder, you won't get anything bound to `IsPrimary` since you've named the controls `nameIsPrimary` - that is the property the model binder looks for.